# How to read a key in Go but continue application if no key pressed within x seconds?

Tags: go, ncurses

This is an easy way to read a key from the console

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

// ...

func readKey() rune {
    char, _, err := reader.ReadRune()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading key: ", err)
    }
    return char
}

// ...

fmt.Println("Checking keyboard input...")    

loop:
for {
    keyb := readKey()
    switch keyb {
    case 'x':
      fmt.Println("x key pressed, exiting loop")
      break loop
    }
}
```

However the issue is the application always waits for a key to be read. What if you want to wait only 5 seconds for a key to be read, and if no key is read, continue the application?

I'm thinking that I must pull in a dependency maybe, such as **ncurses** or a unit (module) that turbopascal had which was called **crt** and had a readkey function.  But is a dependency really necessary or is there an easy way to do it without? Possibly even some defer() tricks, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need external dependencies to achieve this.

You can use a channel and set a timeout on it.

Here's documentation info about that: https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

The key part is making the input go through the channel in a separate goroutine, so that the main thread does not block waiting. You can then decide how long to wait to receive the input through the channel by setting a timeout in the select clause.

And here's a working sample using your post as a base:

```
package main 

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func readKey(input chan rune) {
    char, _, err := reader.ReadRune()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    input <- char
}

func main() {
    input := make(chan rune, 1)
    fmt.Println("Checking keyboard input...")
    go readKey(input)
    select {
        case i := <-input:
            fmt.Printf("Input : %v\n", i)
        case <-time.After(5000 * time.Millisecond):
            fmt.Println("Time out!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and report back. What did people use when there were no such thing as channels, threads, goroutines, etc.? But since go has channels, might as well use them

Comment: They wrote callbacks and/or reactive code (same thing really). Go & CSP provides a cleaner abstraction IMO.

Notice though that the channel (above) has a one place buffer. In the simplest use-case, this is fine. But if there is a repeating need to read characters with a timeout, some more work is needed to design a way to drop unwanted characters if they miss the timeout.

Comment: wonder if using multiple threads or routines is a good idea on a possibly non thread safe command line console.... If it is stuck in a read state (waiting for keyboard input), to just come in and do a println when it is in that state, seems almost like breaking the law.. 

Maybe MS Windows has allowed this to work by luck or on purpose, but I guess console mode programs were never really meant for multi threads/routines , but I'm not sure. I.e. if a readln or read state makes the command line stuck in that state, it seems bad to just force it into a println state when it is in readln.

Comment: cont'd, so I will have to also look into ncurses to see how they do it without using threads or routines, if that's what they do... as I know there are console mode apps out there that have such timeouts, but how? But I appreciate both your answer and Dirk's answer, it does seem to be working on MS Windows either by luck or by design even though my gut tells me that sending a Println to a console (possibly not thread safe) when it is in a readln state, seems dangerous/risky

Comment: @OverflowingHuman I don't know what you mean by "possibly non tread safe command line console", but golang channels are indeed thread safe (that is, you won't need to worry about race conditions)

Comment: @Nevermore yesterday....  it is not AFAIK a matter of whether Go is thread safe, but whether the old dos style console is safe to send a writeln/println when it's in a readln/scanln state, from another thread... Overwriting a readln/scanln with a println call could have bizarre consequences depending on what operating system. But maybe all operating systems are safe this way nowadays. This would need to be checked. Reminds me why console apps are not worth bothering with when you can build a nice GUI app with a message loop and avoid this 1970's style mess. But golang is better at console apps

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most "go-isch" way to do this is using a goroutine and channels. You start two goroutines, one which waits for input, and one which sleeps until after the timeout period. You then use a `select` statement in your main goroutine to check what event happened first (the input, or the timeout). Example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func waitForInput(didInput chan<- bool) {
    // Wait for a valid input here

    didInput <- true
}

func main() {
    didInput := make(chan bool, 1)
    timeout := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        timeout <- true
    }()

    go waitForInput(didInput)

    select {
    case <-didInput:
        fmt.Println("")
        // Continue your application here
    case <-timeout:
        // Input timed out, quit your application here
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it and wondered: it must be bad to have a command line program in a readln state (wait for keyboard input) and then to just come in and hammer it with with a println, when it is already stuck in a readln state (command line/console is not thread safe?). 

It could work just by luck, on some platforms, but is it really good practice to throw a println onto a command line program state that is specifically stuck in a read state waiting for keyboard input... 

It does seem to work, on Windows, not sure about other platforms. But not sure if it is safe! thanks for answer